# Adding column from parent entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I generate a list of people with the below query

```
var officers = db.RootDomains.Where(rd => rd.ID == id)
                                    .SelectMany(rd => rd.Companies)
                                    .SelectMany(c => c.CompanyMatches)
                                    .Select(cm => cm.CompaniesHouseRecord)
                                    .SelectMany(chr => chr.CompanyOfficers);
```

This returns the people that I want but I want to include an extra column on `CompanyOfficers`.

The `CompanyMatches` entity has a property `MatchMethod`.  I want this value to be attached onto every `CompanyOfficer`in the returned dataset.

Is this possible?

Comment: you tried dynamic object inside .SelectMany(chr => chr.CompanyOfficers);

Answer (score 0):

You can't really attach a property from an ancestor object onto a child object. The child object can only contain properties that belong to it. You can try returning an anonymous object, that has all of the properties that you want from the CompanyOfficer plus the MatchMethod property. For instance:

```
var officers = db.RootDomains
                                .SelectMany(rd => rd.Companies)
                                .SelectMany(c => c.CompanyMatches)
                                .Select(cm => cm.CompaniesHouseRecord)
                                .SelectMany(chr => chr.CompanyOfficers)
                                .Select(x => new
                                    {
                                       Id = x.Id, // This would be the Company Officer Id
                                       MatchMethod = x.CompanyHouseRecord.CompanyMatch.MatchMethod, // This would be the ancestor property you want to include
                                       AnyOtherProperty = ...
                                    };
```

This would give you an IEnumerable of objects with all of the properties that you want. There is no way to dynamically add properties to a strongly-typed object howerver.

Comment: `x.CompanyHouseRecord.CompanyMatch.MatchMethod` doesn't work because they are collections not single.